# Resolving Error ("final tuning parameters could not be determined") for MARS model

Tags: r

I am currently working through computational exercises within Applied Predictive Modelling by Max & Kjell and I'm encountering the error in the above Title when executing a MARS model.

The details of the packages and code used have been provided below:

Packages used: AppliedPredictiveModelling and earth.

```
marsFit <- earth(solTrainXtrans, solTrainY)

marsGrid <- expand.grid(degree = 1:2, nprune = 2:38)

set.seed(100)
marsTuned <- train(solTrainXtrans, solTrainY,
                   method = "earth",
                   # declaring the candidate models to test
                   tuneGrid = marsGrid,
                   trcontrol = trainControl(method = "cv")
                   )
```

The error message obtain is as shown below:

```
Error in train.default(solTrainXtrans, solTrainY, method = "earth", tuneGrid = marsGrid,  : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Can anyone please advise on what to do in order to resolve this?